# How to get Dynamic Range Column Reference in Excel :)

Tags: excel, dynamic, range

I have a dynamic range in an Excel sheet.

> `DATA_TABLE =OFFSET(DATA!$B$3,0,0,COUNTA(DATA!$B:$B)-1,0)`

I want to get reference of the third entire column array  to look up a value in it. :)
How can I get this?

> `=VLOOKUP("Some_value_here",COLUMN(DATA_TABLE  -s third column here ),1,) ??????`

How can I do this? :)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INDEX to get the nth column of a multi-column range

`=INDEX(range,0,n)`

[0 indicates all rows]

so in your VLOOKUP that would be  something like

`=VLOOKUP("Some_value_here",INDEX(DATA_TABLE,0,3),1,)`

If you are using VLOOKUP to simply verify that the value exists you might be better of with MATCH.....

Comment: Plus one for  'you might be better off with MATCH'